# Alternative to 'Menu Editor' extension for Firefox

Tags: windows, gratis, web-browser, firefox

**[Menu Editor](https://outgoing.mozilla.org/v1/4f477b93883f93d9fd6e5fb1502d89f03934da6a/https%3A//addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/710)** was a usefull extension to remove/hide the desired items of the different Firefox menus (like "*Open link in a new window*" item, etc).

[image]

Today I installed **Firefox 45.0.1** and the extension becomes not compatible (even doing the known trick to force the compatibility for newer versions), more than that, the author has removed the extension from the Mozilla site, so I don't have any link to show, it just does not exists anymore.

Another person seems have continued the work of the original author in this **[Menu Editor II](https://addons.mozilla.org/ro/firefox/addon/menu-editor-ii/?src=search)** extension, however, this extension is not working properly, it can be installed, but it removes completely some menus (like the menu that is shown when clicking on a tab), so, it is bugged, not working, and also it is discontinued.

Then I'm just looking for a similar extension capable to remove items from Firefox menus, working properlly on **Firefox 45.0.1**.

### Requisites:

- Free
- Works in Firefox 45.0.1 (x86)

Comment: Can you describe how it must work? I don't know this tool.

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul Sorry I arrived too late to read your comment, but I answer you anyways:The extension should show a graphical user-interface on which will be displayed the current Firefox's context-menus elements, then select what options to remove from each contextmenu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [Menu Wizard](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/s3menu-wizard/).

It allows you to remove, move, and rename menus and menuitems with ease.  It even lets you modify many keyboard shortcuts.

It works on Firefox, Thunderbird, and SeaMonkey.

[image: screenshot]
*Image Source: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/s3menu-wizard/*

Comment: Thanks for answer, but maybe do you know whether the donation webpage of the extension is displayed once, or is randomlly?. I really don't want an extension that is remembering me to donate randomlly when I run my webbrowser... that would be very annonying.

Comment: @ElektroStudios I agree.  I reviewed the source code.  It only shows the donation page on initial install and when a new version is released.  This also matches my experience with it.